# Firefox warning .. can I suppress it so it DOES NOT show?

Tags: javascript, pdf, firefox, show-hide, suppress-warnings

Firefox alert .. can I suppress it so it DOES NOT show? 
I only want to display the PDF but Firefox displays a yellow action bar with the message 
"This PDF document contains forms. The filling of form fields is not supported" and an "X" to close the message or "Open with a different browser"
Can I prevent this from appearing at all? 
I have a C# web application

Comment: Firefox is not able to provide all the features required to handle the pdf in a way it is supposed to be - like modify the content of the form fields. Why do you want to keep the end user unaware of this?

Comment: I am using an iframe to just DISPLAY the pdf. If the user clicks the "Open with another browser" .. it breaks the flow of the application .. opens with Adobe in a separate window! If they click the "X" to close the message all is well! But I really do not need the firefox warning ... Fyi there is no warning with Chrome or IE or Edge and I need the same behaviour with Firefox